# Alternative Definition of Markov Property.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

currently I am trying to solve the following exercise (17.1.1) in Klenke Probability Theory, which states the following:

Let $(X_t)_{t \in I}$ be a stochastic process and denote by $\mathcal{F}_{\leq t} = \sigma(X_s : s \in I, \; s \leq t)$ the sigma-algebra of the past until time $t$, while $\mathcal{F}_{\geq t}$ denotes respectively the sigma-algebra of the future. Then one has the following equivalence:

The process $(X_t)_{t \in I}$ admits the (elementary) Markov property iff both $\mathcal{F}_{\leq t}$ and $\mathcal{F}_{\geq t}$ are independent given $\sigma(X_t)$, where the definition follows:

**Conditional Independence**

A family of sub-sigma algebras $(\mathcal{A}_i)_{i \in I} \subset \mathcal{F}$ is called independent of the sub-sigma algebra $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{F}$ if for every finite $J \subset I$ one has

$$
P(\cap_{j \in J} A_j \mid \mathcal{A}) = \prod_{j \in J} P(A_j \mid \mathcal{A}) \quad \text{almost surely}.
$$

My try so far:

For the first direction, suppose that $X$ admits the Markov Property then let $(A_j)_{j \in J} \subseteq \sigma(X_s)_{s \leq t}$ be a finite family of events from the sigma algebra of the past, observe that for $A = \cap_{j \in J} A_j$ one has almost surely
$$
P(A \mid \sigma(X_t)) \stackrel{Def.}{=} E[ \mathbf{1}_A \mid \sigma(X_t) ] \stackrel{M.P}{=} E[ \mathbf{1}_A \mid \mathcal{F}_t ] = \mathbf{1}_A = \prod_{j \in J} \mathbf{1}_{A_j} = \prod_{j \in J} P(A_j \mid \mathcal{F}_t) \stackrel{M.P}{=} \prod_{j \in J} P(A_j \mid \sigma(X_t)),
$$
where we used that due to the filtration property $\mathbf{1}_{A_j}$ are $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable. Now for the sigma algebra of the future let again $(A_j)_{j \in J}$ be a finite family of events of $\mathcal{F}_{t \geq}$ then observe first that by the Markov Property one has
$$
P(A \mid \sigma(X_t) ) \stackrel{M.P}{=} P(A \mid \mathcal{F}_t) \stackrel{Def.}{=} E[\mathbf{1}_{A} \mid \mathcal{F}_t],
$$
then since for all $j \in J$ one has $A_j \in \mathcal{F}_j$ where $j \geq t$ but now I am stuck since I cannot use the tower property in a good way. I am sure there is a connection with independence and conditional expectation but right now I don't see it, any hints?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$(\Rightarrow)$. Suppose $X$ is Markov. Then for any $s\leq t$ and $B \in \mathscr{B}$, $P(X_t \in B|X_s)=P(X_t \in B|\mathscr{F}_s)$ and equivalently for all bounded measurable $f$ we have $E[f(X_t)|\mathscr{F}_s]=E[f(X_t)|X_s]$. We have for $  s \leq  t$ and $A\in \mathscr{B}, F \in \mathscr{F}_s$
$$P(\{X_t\in A\}\cap F|\mathscr{F}_s)=P(X_t \in A|\mathscr{F}_s)\mathbf{1}_{F}=P(X_t \in A|X_s)\mathbf{1}_{F}$$
Since $\sigma(X_s)\subseteq \mathscr{F}_s$, we take the conditional expectations:
$$P(\{X_t\in A\}\cap F|X_s)=P(X_t \in A|X_s)P(F|X_s)$$
So $\sigma(X_t)$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_s$ conditionally on $\sigma(X_s)$, $\forall t \geq s$. Now, similarly, for $s\leq u\leq t$

$$\begin{aligned}P(\{X_t \in A\}\cap \{X_u \in B\}\cap F|\mathscr{F}_s)&=P(\{X_t \in A\}\cap \{X_u \in B\}|\mathscr{F}_s)\mathbf{1}_{F}=\\
&=E[P(X_t \in A|\mathscr{F}_u)\mathbf{1}_{\{X_u \in B\}}|\mathscr{F}_s]\mathbf{1}_{F}=\\
&=E[P(X_t \in A|X_u)\mathbf{1}_{\{X_u \in B\}}|\mathscr{F}_s]\mathbf{1}_{F}=\\
&=E[P(\{X_t \in A\}\cap\{X_u \in B\}|X_u)|\mathscr{F}_s]\mathbf{1}_{F}=\\
&=E[P(\{X_t \in A\}\cap\{X_u \in B\}|X_u)|X_s]\mathbf{1}_{F}=\\
&=E[P(\{X_t \in A\}\cap\{X_u \in B\}|\mathscr{F}_u)|X_s]\mathbf{1}_{F}=\\
&=P(\{X_t \in A\}\cap\{X_u \in B\}|X_s)\mathbf{1}_{F}\end{aligned}$$
and ultimately
$$P(\{X_t \in A\}\cap \{X_u \in B\}\cap F|X_s)=P(\{X_t \in A\}\cap\{X_u \in B\}|X_s)P(F|X_s)$$
So $(X_{t_1},X_{t_2},...,X_{t_n}),\,s\leq t_1\leq t_2 \leq ... \leq t_n<\infty$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_s$ conditionally on $\sigma(X_s)$ by a $\pi$-$\lambda$ argument with the rectangle sets $A_1\times A_2\times ... \times A_n\in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Now we can see that
$$\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{s\leq t_1\leq ... \leq t_n<\infty}\sigma(X_{t_1},...,X_{t_n})\subseteq\{G \in \mathscr{F}_{\geq s}:P(G\cap F|X_s)=P(G|X_s)P(F|X_s),\,\forall F \in \mathscr{F}_s\}$$
The family on the rhs is straightforwardly seen to be a Dynkin system (i.e. a $\lambda$-system) contained in $\mathscr{F}_{\geq s}$, while the family on the lhs is a $\cap$-stable system (i.e. a $\pi$ system). The lhs generates $\mathscr{F}_{\geq s}=\sigma(t \geq s,X_t)$, and the conclusion follows.

$(\Leftarrow)$. Suppose $P(G \cap F|X_s)=P(G|X_s)P(F|X_s),\,\forall F \in \mathscr{F}_s,\forall G \in \mathscr{F}_{\geq s}$. We have for $F \in \mathscr{F}_s$ (and ofc since $\{X_t \in A\}\in \mathscr{F}_{\geq s}$)
$$\begin{aligned}E[\mathbf{1}_{F}\mathbf{1}_{\{X_t \in A\}}]&=E[E[\mathbf{1}_F|X_s]P(X_t \in A|X_s)]=\\
&=E[\mathbf{1}_FP(X_t \in A|X_s)]\end{aligned}$$
so $P(X_t \in A|\mathscr{F}_s)=P(X_t \in A|X_s)$ a.s. by definition of conditional expectation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, as I see it, the proof seems to be correct. For me what is a bit surprised and what I missed is that checking that $\sigma(X_t)$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_s$ given $\sigma(X_s)$, which is a bit more than the definition. since one also has the relationsship between $\sigma(X_t)$ and $\mathcal{F}_s$, why was this statement intuitive for you?

Comment: You're welcome @a.s.graduatestudent! The intuition is that $X_t$, the process being Markov, depends only on $X_s$ and 'not on the rest of past information'; it is just how Markov processes are informally (but rightly) understood to behave. Formalizing this intuition becomes then part of the argument.

Comment: I see I already had that in mind, could one reformulate this in a statement that is somehow close to $mathcal(F)_s$ is trivial with respect to $sigma(X_s)$ (Provides no new information, i.e. is just the trivial signa algebra)?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is equivalent to the trivial sigma algebra in this setting. I think the formalization you seek is just the Markov property itself as stated in the definition! @a.s.graduatestudent I beg your pardon if I am not getting what you mean.

Comment: Yes you are correct, it is definitly not trivial. I simply forgot that the M.P. is not just simply about the relationsship between the sigma algebra $\sigma(X_s)$ and the past, say $\mathcal{F}_s$ but also of $\sigma(X_s)$ and $\mathcal{F}_s$ with respect to $X_t$ matters. Moreover, this is just kinda special, since also Klenke mentions in Ex. 12.23 that one has **no monotonicity** for conditional independence, where with the Markov Property + Proof above I believe it is now enough to check on $\mathcal{F}_{\leq t}$ and $\mathcal{F}_{\geq t}$, to conclude independence on $\sigma(X_t)$ no?

Comment: @a.s.graduatestudent most likely because of the too concise format of the comments, I don't fully get what you are asking. A suggestion: open a new question where you introduce Klenke's statement (which is true) and what you specifically want to know in the Markov setting (also by linking this question in the text) :)

Comment: I actually figured it out today, but thank you for the good conversation, I learned a lot from this :)